# Trying to remove an empty column - winform

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, visual-studio, winforms

I created a small project in winform to display data grid view from mhtml file.
everything works fine. i wanted to add something in my project : when i see an empty column i wanted to remove it if there is one.
i almost did it but i have an error.
here is the code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MHtmlTablesHunter
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private readonly string ConvertedFileName = "page.html";

        private readonly List<string> ColumnsToSeparate = new List<string>() { "life limit", "interval" }; // Delete these columns 

        private readonly List<string> ExtraColumnsToAdd = new List<string>() { "Calendar", "Flight Hours", "Landing" }; // Add these columns
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Text = $"MhtmlTablesHunter v{Application.ProductVersion}";

        }

        //browse for specific file type , in this case its .mhtml
        private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
            {
                openFileDialog.Title = "Please choose the MHTML file";
                openFileDialog.Filter = "MHTML files (*.mhtml)|*.mhtml;";  //the file type specified here
                openFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = false;

                if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    textBoxSourceFile.Text = openFileDialog.FileName;
                    checkAndExtractTable();
                }
            }

        }

        private void checkAndExtractTable()
        {
            string sourcePath =   textBoxSourceFile.Text;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sourcePath)) //check if the input file path is not empty
            {
                if (File.Exists(sourcePath)) //check if the input file path is exists
                {
                    Task.Run(async () => await ExtractTable(sourcePath)); //run the extraction process in a thread for the UI to be more responsive
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Source file doesn't exist.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select the source file.");
            }
        }
        //This part concern the headers, rows and columns
        public async Task<string> ExtractTable(string sourcePath)
        {
            try
            {
                var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

                var converter = new MimeConverter(); //converter used to convert mhtml file to html

                if (File.Exists(ConvertedFileName))  //check if previously converted file is exist
                {
                    File.Delete(ConvertedFileName);  //delete the file
                }
                using (FileStream sourceStream = File.OpenRead(sourcePath))
                {
                    using (FileStream destinationStream = File.Open("page.html", FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        await converter.Convert(sourceStream, destinationStream);  //convert the file to html, it will be stored in the application folder
                    }
                }

                doc.Load(ConvertedFileName);  //load the html
                //var tables = doc.GetElementbyId("d19924139e528_grid"); //get the 7th table by its id, we can get the table id by inspecting element in the internet explorer
                var tables = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table"); //get all the tables
                HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode table = null;


                if (tables.Count > 0)
                {
                    table = tables[tables.Count - 1]; //take the last table
                }


                if (table != null) //if the table exists
                {
                    dataGridView1.Invoke((Action)delegate //we use delegate because we accessing the datagridview from a different thread
                    {
                        this.dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
                        this.dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
                    });

                    var rows = table.SelectNodes(".//tr"); //get all the rows

                    var nodes = rows[0].SelectNodes("th|td"); //get the header row values, first item will be the header row always
                    string LifeLimitColumnName = ColumnsToSeparate.Where(c => nodes.Any(n => n.InnerText.ToLower().Contains(c))).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(LifeLimitColumnName))
                    {
                        LifeLimitColumnName = "Someunknowncolumn";
                    }
                    List<string> headers = new List<string>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.Count; i++) // LOOP
                    {
                        headers.Add(nodes[i].InnerText);
                        if (!nodes[i].InnerText.ToLower().Contains(LifeLimitColumnName))
                        {
                            dataGridView1.Invoke((Action)delegate
                            {
                                dataGridView1.Columns.Add("", nodes[i].InnerText);
                            });
                        }
                    }

                    int indexOfLifeLimitColumn = headers.FindIndex(h => h.ToLower().Contains(LifeLimitColumnName));
                    if (indexOfLifeLimitColumn > -1)
                    {
                        foreach (var eh in ExtraColumnsToAdd)
                        {
                            dataGridView1.Invoke((Action)delegate
                            {
                                dataGridView1.Columns.Add("", eh); //add extra header to the datagridview
                            });

                        }
                    }

                    int[] rowDataCount = new int[dataGridView1.Columns.Count];
                    Array.Clear(rowDataCount, 0, rowDataCount.Length);

                    for (int i = 1; i < rows.Count; i++) ///loop through rest of the rows
                    {
                        var row = rows[i];
                        var nodes2 = row.SelectNodes("th|td"); //get all columns in the current row
                        List<string> values = new List<string>(); //list to store row values
                        for (int x = 0; x < nodes2.Count; x++)
                        {
                            //rowes.Cells[x].Value = nodes2[x].InnerText;
                            string cellText = nodes2[x].InnerText.Replace("&nbsp;", " ");
                            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cellText)) {
                                rowDataCount[x]++;
                            }
                            values.Add(cellText); //add the cell value in the list

                        }
                        // Factory for -> Calendar, Flight Hours, Landings
                        if (indexOfLifeLimitColumn > -1)
                        {
                            values.RemoveAt(indexOfLifeLimitColumn);
                            string lifeLimitValue = nodes2[indexOfLifeLimitColumn].InnerText.Replace("&nbsp;", " ");
                            string[] splittedValues = lifeLimitValue.Split(' ');
                            for (int y = 0; y < ExtraColumnsToAdd.Count; y++)
                            {
                                if (ExtraColumnsToAdd[y] == "Calendar")
                                {
                                    string valueToAdd = string.Empty;
                                    string[] times = new string[] { "Years", "Year", "Months", "Month", "Day", "Days" };
                                    if (splittedValues.Any(s => times.Any(t => t == s)))
                                    {
                                        var timeFound = times.Where(t => splittedValues.Any(s => s == t)).FirstOrDefault();
                                        int index = splittedValues.ToList().FindIndex(s => s.Equals(timeFound));
                                        valueToAdd = $"{splittedValues[index - 1]} {timeFound}";
                                    }
                                    values.Add(valueToAdd);
                                }
                                else if (ExtraColumnsToAdd[y] == "Flight Hours")
                                {
                                    string valueToAdd = string.Empty;
                                    if (splittedValues.Any(s => s == "FH"))
                                    {
                                        int index = splittedValues.ToList().FindIndex(s => s.Equals("FH"));
                                        valueToAdd = $"{splittedValues[index - 1]} FH";
                                    }
                                    values.Add(valueToAdd);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    string valueToAdd = string.Empty;
                                    if (splittedValues.Any(s => s == "LDG"))
                                    {
                                        int index = splittedValues.ToList().FindIndex(s => s.Equals("LDG"));
                                        valueToAdd = $"{splittedValues[index - 1]} LDG";
                                    }
                                    values.Add(valueToAdd);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        dataGridView1.Invoke((Action)delegate
                        {
                            this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(values.ToArray()); //add the list as a row
                        });

                        int removedCount = 0;
                        for (int index = 0; index < rowDataCount.Length; index++) {
                            if (rowDataCount[index] == 0) {
                                dataGridView1.Invoke((Action)delegate
                                {
                                    this.dataGridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(index - removedCount);
                                    removedCount++;
                                });
                            }
                        }


                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            return string.Empty;
        }

        private void textBoxSourceFile_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

here is the design code of the winform project

```
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Form1));
            this.textBoxSourceFile = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.btnBrowse = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.dataGridView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // textBoxSourceFile
            // 
            this.textBoxSourceFile.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.textBoxSourceFile.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(51, 38);
            this.textBoxSourceFile.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4);
            this.textBoxSourceFile.Name = "textBoxSourceFile";
            this.textBoxSourceFile.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(903, 30);
            this.textBoxSourceFile.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // btnBrowse
            // 
            this.btnBrowse.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.btnBrowse.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(999, 38);
            this.btnBrowse.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4);
            this.btnBrowse.Name = "btnBrowse";
            this.btnBrowse.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(93, 28);
            this.btnBrowse.TabIndex = 1;
            this.btnBrowse.Text = "Browse";
            this.btnBrowse.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.btnBrowse.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnBrowse_Click);
            // 
            // dataGridView1
            // 
            this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
            this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToResizeRows = false;
            this.dataGridView1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
            this.dataGridView1.BackgroundColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlLight;
            this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
            this.dataGridView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(51, 118);
            this.dataGridView1.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4);
            this.dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
            this.dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = false;
            this.dataGridView1.RowHeadersWidth = 62;
            this.dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1042, 467);
            this.dataGridView1.TabIndex = 2;
            //this.dataGridView1.CellContentClick += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.dataGridView1_CellContentClick);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(12F, 25F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1136, 636);
            this.Controls.Add(this.dataGridView1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.btnBrowse);
            this.Controls.Add(this.textBoxSourceFile);
            this.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("$this.Icon")));
            this.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4);
            this.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1086, 557);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            this.Text = "Form1";
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBoxSourceFile;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnBrowse;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dataGridView1;
    }
}
```

When i run it, i have this error

[click here to see the picture](https://ibb.co/1MT4J7h)

Comment: Check the value of  `index - removedCount`. the code with error is not in the code you shared

Comment: sorry i added the wrong code, here is the good one. Sorry again !!

Comment: Life would be a lot simpler if you put this data into a `DataTable` or `List<T>` and then binded the grid to it; you wouldn't have to invoke all over the place

Comment: Can't reproduce this, unless `rowDataCount.Length` is greater than `datagridView1.Columns.Count`

Comment: is it possible to send me the correct code please? i'm a begginer in c#. I try to do my best. Thanks a lot

Comment: Also, is it possible to bring the code in the list, because after that i want to export the datagrid somewhere. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly you have more columns in your array than your grid - I can't see anything that removes a column after you declare the array, but perhaps it would be better to key the removing of a column off of whether the actual grid column has data rather than a memory of whether you put any data in it. Let's ask the grid "for every column, do all rows for that column have no value? remove the column":

```
dataGridView1.Invoke((Action)delegate
{
    var rowNumerable = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>();

    for (int i = dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (rowNumerable.All(r => string.IsNullOrEmpty(r.Cells[i].Value?.ToString())))
            dataGridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(i);
    }
});
```

Side note, my column removing loop runs in reverse instead, because it means that removing column index `i` only affects columns `> i`, but we've already processed them. It doesn't affect indexing of column indexes we have yet to process that are `< i` so we dont need to mess around with indexes.

TLDR: If you're removing things from a collection you're looping over, looping in reverse can make things simpler

Answer (score 0):

Finally i did it thanks a lot for everyone. Caius jayd you're right. I follow your intruction. it's working now. Here is the code :

````
                    dataGridView1.Invoke((Action)delegate
                    {
                        int[] rowDataCount = new int[dataGridView1.Columns.Count];
                        Array.Clear(rowDataCount, 0, rowDataCount.Length);

                        for (int row_i = 0; row_i < this.dataGridView1.RowCount; row_i++)
                        {
                            for (int col_i = 0; col_i < this.dataGridView1.ColumnCount; col_i++)
                            {
                                var cell = this.dataGridView1.Rows[row_i].Cells[col_i];
                                string cellText = cell.Value.ToString();
                                if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cellText))
                                {
                                    rowDataCount[col_i] += 1;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        int removedCount = 0;
                        for (int index = 0; index < rowDataCount.Length; index++)
                        {
                            if (rowDataCount[index] == 0)
                            {
                                this.dataGridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(index - removedCount);
                                removedCount++;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }```
````